# Adding the "tika-parser-microsoft-module" gives me a NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, apache-tika

With only tika-core in my pom, i found the correct mimeType the most of the time, but the problem is when i use the docx files, i retrieve actually `application/x-tika-ooxml`, but i should retrieve `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document instead` for exemple. So i decided to add `tika-parser-microsoft-module` and to change my code to retrieve the right mimeType...

**My .pom and code before adding the `tika-parser-microsoft-module` and having a NullPointerException yet**

`.pom` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`method` :

```
public String retrieveMimeType(InputStream stream) throws IOException, TikaException { 
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    String detectedType = tika.detect(stream);
    return detectedType;
}
```

**And after adding the microsoft modules parsers in the .pom and after editing the code to retrieve the right mimeType for the docx files :**

`.pom` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parser-microsoft-module</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`code` :

```
public String retrieveMimeType(InputStream stream, String filename) throws IOException, TikaException {
    TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
    Detector detector = config.getDetector();

    TikaInputStream streams = TikaInputStream.get(stream);

    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.add(TikaCoreProperties.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, filename);
    //This line occurs the NullPointerException
    MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(stream, metadata);
     
    return mediaType.toString();
}
```

So what can i do to retrieve the right mimeType, and fix my NullPointerException ?

Comment: you can debug your code and check what variable isn't initialized.